# What is the proper(managed by the pipeline) directory in vnext builds that can be used for temp files?

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops

In our builds there is sometimes a need (for one or another reason) to copy/create some files that are required during the build, but are not actually [artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/artifacts-overview?view=azure-devops).

As it is a bit problematic to guarantee cleanup/deletion of those files after the build in all cases, they should obviously be stored in some directory that is managed by the build pipeline, so when the build completes or thereafter that directory will be automatically cleaned up.

So far we have been using [Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) to get the expected behavior as it is the only one that is

> purged before each new build, so you don't have to clean it up yourself.

Still, as such files are not really artifacts, it seems to be slightly inappropriate.

Perhaps there is a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

`$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` can also be configured to be purged before each build. That may be more appropriate for temporary build outputs.

However, there's no right answer to this.